# Supplying a code block as one of multiple method parameters

Tags: scala

Consider these overloaded  `groupBy` signatures:

```
  def groupBy[K](f: T => K)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K]): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])] = withScope {
    groupBy[K](f, defaultPartitioner(this))
  }

  def groupBy[K](
      f: T => K,
      numPartitions: Int)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K]): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])] = withScope {
    groupBy(f, new HashPartitioner(numPartitions))
  }
```

A ***correct/working*** invocation of the former is as follows:

```
val groupedRdd = df.rdd.groupBy{ r => r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId"))}
```

But I am unable to determine how to add the second parameter. Here is the obvious attempt - which gives **syntax errors**:

```
val groupedRdd = df.rdd.groupBy{ r => r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId")), 
nPartitions}
```

I had also tried (also with **syntax errors**) :

```
val groupedRdd = df.rdd.groupBy({ r => r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId"))},
 nPartitions)
```

btw Here is an approach that **does** work .. but I am looking for the inline syntax

```
def  func(r: Row)  = r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId"))
val groupedRdd = df.rdd.groupBy( func _, nPartitions)
```

Comment: How about this: `df.rdd.groupBy({ r: Row => r.get....}, nPartitions)`

Comment: @yǝsʞǝlA  That's already shown as the second *syntax errors* example above

Comment: note the type annotation `Row`

Comment: ok i'll try that

Comment: that works : pls make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a generic method with type parameters `T`, `K`, Scala sometimes can't infer what types those should be from the context. In such cases you can help it by providing type annotation like this:

```
df.rdd.groupBy({ r: Row => r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId")) }, nPartitions)
```

This is also the reason why this approach works:

```
def func(r: Row)  = r.getString(r.fieldIndex("centroidId"))
val groupedRdd = df.rdd.groupBy(func _, nPartitions)
```

This fixes the type for `r` to be a `Row` similarly to the approach above.